# What is the best way/data structure to implement a custom Clipboard?

Tags: c#, data-structures, queue, unity-game-engine, clipboard

I'm working in Unity3D with C# and working on a very simple file manager for my game.
There are simple operations that you could perform on the files/folders, one of them is "Cut"
(and maybe "Copy", for later)

For better imagining of what's happening:

[image]

For copying and pasting, I need a custom `Clipboard`. I thought of two data structures to implement it with, a `Stack` and a `Queue`. The problem with the stack, is that if I cut 'a', 'b' and 'c', they'll get pasted in reverse, LIFO. So I thought a queue is better.

```
public class Clipboard<T>
{
    private SLLQueue<T> queue; // SLL stands for SinglyLinkedList, the queue is implemented that way...

    public Clipboard()
    {
        queue = new SLLQueue<T>();
    }

    public void Add(T data)
    {
        queue.Clear();
        Append(data);
    }

    public void Add(T[] data)
    {
        queue.Clear();
        foreach (var d in data)
            Append(d);
    }

    private void Append(T data)
    {
        queue.Push(data);
    }

    public T[] Clear()
    {
        int len = queue.Count;
        var data = new T[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            data[i] = queue.Pop();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

Is this good enough? - Is this the right data structure? - And did I implement the Clipboard's operations the right way?

Thanks a lot for your help.

EDIT: I'm NOT looking into the system's Clipboard.

EDIT: I've used the queue implementation, here's how the clipboard will work in action.

```
    public void CutSelection()
    {
        // if there's already something cut, change its fade/alpha back to normal
        var clipContents = fileManager.Clipboard.Clear();
        foreach (var c in clipContents)
            c.Icon.alpha = 1f;

        // adds all the currently selected items to the clip
        fileManager.Clipboard.Add(Selection);

        // cut their alpha to half
        foreach (var s in Selection)
            s.Icon.alpha = CUT_ALPHA;
    }

public void Paste()
{
     // clear the clip / get the content inside it, get their alpha back to full and move them to the current folder
    var clipContents = Clipboard.Clear();
    if (clipContents != null) {
        for (int i = 0, len = clipContents.Length; i < len; i++) {
            clipContents[i].Icon.alpha = 1;
            clipContents[i].MoveTo(currentFolder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A few questions: A) why not System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>, and B) why not System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard?

Comment: For pure customization reasons. A) My queue is implemented via a linked list, and I believe the one in the collections is implemented via an array, or a list maybe? - For what I need, a linked list is better, performance and storage-wise. B) Because it has a lot more than what I need. Again, with custom stuff you have more control. Plus I'm in a learning process and trying to make everything myself to learn more how things work.

Comment: Aren't most clipboards either a) Single storage or b) A list (not a queue or stack)? That will make finding a "best practice" awfully difficult.. and perhaps they are this way because of the questions you're raising.

Comment: The only problem I found with a stack or queue, is that you can't conveniently get all the contents of the clipboard without clearing out the stack/queue (the I way I did ^). With a list I can get the contents whenever I want. What I like about a queue/stack, is that you only allocate memory when you want to (assuming that the stack/queue is implemented via a linked list), unlike a list where it allocates by the powers of 2. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc Extra luggage, I don't want that. I think the queue works just fine with what I'm doing, single storage, although I can easily change that.

Comment: I suspect you are prematurely optimizing. For starters, a traditional linked list is almost never the correct solution to even the plain, old, sequential access list. Secondly, there isn't any indication that you need such tightly controlled memory: the empty array elements will only take up 8 bytes each; just how many objects can the user cut and paste to make that a significant problem? Your needs for the clipboard are founded in real requirements (though you will lose interactivity with other apps), but I don't see anything that requires a custom collection  (a code smell in most cases).

Comment: Actually, with every call to Cut overwriting the previous one, I'm not seeing the point of the Clear call on the queue at all. What is the type of Selection? Instead of copying all of its elements from whatever Selection is to the Clipboard queue, why not just overwrite the clipboard's collection with Selection?

Comment: Selection is a List<FolderContent> where FolderContent: Folder|FILE. If you mean the call right at the start of CutSelection, then you're right, there was no need. But the fact that I'm changing the alpha once I cut something, means that I must get the alpha back if I'm cutting something else, thats why I need to get the clip's contents. If you mean the call inside Add, you're right as well, but since I'm dealing with a queue, its easier to nuke it. Otherwise I'd have to add extra functionality like GetAt(i) (which I already have in my linked list) otherwise I cant overwrite the values easily.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Clipboard Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx).
Here's an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/637ys738.aspx) to add and retrieve data with it.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I know how to use the Clipboard class. I'm not looking to deal with the System's clipboard, I just need a clipboard structure.

Comment: This is not what the OP wants. They want to implement a stack or queue based clipboard. The built in Clipboard class is exactly as I stated in my comment above - single storage.